# Converting suffixes to integer

Tags: python

I've been working on something that scrapes the text off a site, compares it to the minimum and then prints the result. Here's what i'm working with:

snip

( yes i define what the variable 'group_id' is, gets random ids or the id that is chosen )

The currency has suffixes | ex: 1K, 1M, 1B, etc and I was wondering how you would convert it to a number without commas depending on its suffix. I tried everything, no solution so hopefully I can figure this out finally.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code so we can make this reproducable

Comment: @LeviLesches alright, i've posted almost all of the code.

Comment: what number do you want for say 1k.. 1000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all prefixes are at the end you can do the following using a dictionary of values.

```
sizes_dict = {'B': 1, 'K': 1000, 'M': 1000000}

data = '12M'

for k, v in sizes_dict.items():
    if data[-1] == k:
        no_letters = int(data[:-1]) * v

print(no_letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on the information you posted, I suppose that the string may vary like: 1, 2.3K, 5.8M, 7B (examples). To cast this suffixes in normal value you may use the following code, which construct the dict of suffixes and it's coefficients, then if value contains one of the suffixes, then multiply value on corresponding coefficient:

```
suffixes = {'K': 1000, 'M': 1000000, 'B': 1000000000}
value = '3.2B' #  for example
if value[-1] in suffixes.keys():
  value = float(value[:-1]) * suffixes.get(value[-1])
```

hope it helps

Comment: not all of the numbers will have suffixes in them, some will be normal and some may have suffixes. anyways, ive tested this and printed the before and after and got this: 

`Before Robux: 1,637
After Robux: 1,637`

Comment: in my code, if number has suffix it will convert the value, else it won't touch it. I couldn't understand what you mean in `Before Robux: 1,637 After Robux: 1,637`, since it's not a number, it's just plain text?!